# set ruby hash element value by array of keys

Tags: ruby, hash

here is what i got:

```
hash = {:a => {:b => [{:c => old_val}]}}
keys = [:a, :b, 0, :c]
new_val = 10
```

hash structure and set of keys can vary.
i need to get

```
hash[:a][:b][0][:c] == new_val
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) to traverse your nested structures:

```
hash = {:a => {:b => [{:c => "foo"}]}}
keys = [:a, :b, 0, :c]

keys.inject(hash) {|structure, key| structure[key]}
# => "foo"
```

So, you just need to modify this to do a set on the last key. Perhaps something like

```
last_key = keys.pop
# => :c

nested_hash = keys.inject(hash) {|structure, key| structure[key]}
# => {:c => "foo"}

nested_hash[last_key] = "bar"

hash
# => {:a => {:b => [{:c => "bar"}]}}
```

Comment: thanks. ended up with `d=b.pop` `b.inject(a) {|s,k| s[k]}[d] = 20`

Answer (score 3):

Similar to Andy's, but you can use `Symbol#to_proc` to shorten it.

```
hash = {:a => {:b => [{:c => :old_val}]}}
keys = [:a, :b, 0, :c]
new_val = 10
keys[0...-1].inject(hash, &:fetch)[keys.last] = new_val
```

Comment: Nice! I've never used `fetch` on an array before, so I didn't think of it!